# Phonegap Permission for camera

Tags: html, cordova, phonegap-build

I cannot get my app properly working I target android but I use a `config.xml` to build my app in phonegap. What do I need to add here to make my app show camera permission when installing my app?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0" id="com.sample.com"  version = "1.0.0" versionCode = "1" >`enter code here`

    <name>sample</name>
    <description>sample</description>
    <author>sample</author>
    <gap:platforms>
        <gap:platform name="ios" />
        <gap:platform name="android" />
        <gap:platform name="webos" />
        <gap:platform name="symbian.wrt" />
        <gap:platform name="blackberry" project="widgets"/>


    </gap:platforms>

    <icon src="icon.png" />
    <preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.6.3" />
    <feature id="blackberry.media.camera" />
    <plugin name="Camera" value="org.apache.cordova.CameraLauncher" />

    <access origin="*" subdomains="true" />
    <access uri="*" subdomains="true" />
    <access uri="http://redasmobile.esy.es/" subdomains="true" />
    
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/network"/>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/geolocation"/>
    <feature name="InAppBrowser">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.InAppBrowser" />

    </feature>



    <preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="false" />
    <preference name="target-device" value="universal" />

<feature name="Camera">
    <param name="blackberry-package" value="org.apache.cordova.camera.Camera" />
</feature>

</widget>
```

Comment: I think you sould better start with reading the official documentation. Your code seems so wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add those lines to your config.xml

```
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/camera" />
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/file" /><!-- WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE; required for camera to write to camera roll -->
```

Comment: How relevant is this answer 4 yeas later? Can we confirm that this method still works?

Answer (score -1):

Do you use the cli command ie cordova build android or do you use build.phonegap.com ?
If you use the client, you have to do a : cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.camera 
If you use build phonegap you have to add

> `<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.camera" version="0.2.4" />`

in your config.xml